# Rails CMS Casein and Validation of Uniqueness

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

Hello I keep receiving an Error when i try to add a uniqueness validation to my Rails [Casein](https://github.com/russellquinn/casein) (CMS for Rails) controller. Im not sure what Im doing wrong but I keep receiving this error:

> ActionController::RoutingError - undefined method `validates' for
>   Casein::ItemsController:Class:

I used the Casein Scaffold to Generate the below code, only added the `validates :order, uniqueness: true` on the 3rd line. How can I make it so that `:order`, which is an integer field type, is unique in my DB?

```
# Scaffolding generated by Casein v5.1.1.5

module Casein
  class ItemsController < Casein::CaseinController
    validates :order, uniqueness: true


    ## optional filters for defining usage according to Casein::AdminUser access_levels
    # before_filter :needs_admin, :except => [:action1, :action2]
    # before_filter :needs_admin_or_current_user, :only => [:action1, :action2]

    def index
      @casein_page_title = 'Items'
        @items = Item.order(sort_order(:title)).paginate :page => params[:page]
    end

    def show
      @casein_page_title = 'View item'
      @item = Item.find params[:id]
    end

    def new
      @casein_page_title = 'Add a new item'
        @item = Item.new
    end

    def create
      @item = Item.new item_params

      if @item.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Item created'
        redirect_to casein_items_path
      else
        flash.now[:warning] = 'There were problems when trying to create a new item'
        render :action => :new
      end
    end

    def update
      @casein_page_title = 'Update item'

      @item = Item.find params[:id]

      if @item.update_attributes item_params
        flash[:notice] = 'Item has been updated'
        redirect_to casein_items_path
      else
        flash.now[:warning] = 'There were problems when trying to update this item'
        render :action => :show
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @item = Item.find params[:id]

      @item.destroy
      flash[:notice] = 'Item has been deleted'
      redirect_to casein_items_path
    end

    private

      def item_params
        params.require(:item).permit(:title, :caption, :url, :description, :order, :image)
      end

  end
end
```

Thanks all for your time and help!

Comment: If you want to ensure that it is unique *in your database*, then you should setup database rules for that column. That's the only way to really ensure uniqueness in the DB

Comment: and if my DB already has `:order` as an existing column, what would be the best way to make it unique in the DB?  

`rails g migration add_index :item, [:order], :unique => true`??      

If this does work, Will rails throw an error if I try to enter in a `:order` that already exists in the DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about that gem, but in rails, the validations belong in the files that define models, not controllers.

Judging by this line of code of the gem you mentioned:
https://github.com/russellquinn/casein/blob/master/app/models/casein/admin_user.rb#L26
it should work the same way with Casein. (Notice that the file defines a model, not a controller).

Comment: Thanks for the help! totally went full idiot for a little.